# How to change the colour of specific boxplots

Tags: python, pandas, colors, boxplot

Code:

```
df2020 = transport_data.loc['2020']
df2021 = transport_data.loc['2021']
df2022 = transport_data.loc['2022']

fig = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,7))
ax = [
    plt.subplot(131),
    plt.subplot(132),
    plt.subplot(133) ]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
df2020.boxplot(grid=False, rot=90, fontsize=10, ax = ax[0])
df2021.boxplot(grid=False, rot=90, fontsize=10, ax = ax[1])
df2022.boxplot(grid=False, rot=90, fontsize=10, ax = ax[2])


ax[0].set_xlabel('Types of Passengers', fontsize = '12')
ax[1].set_xlabel('Types of Passengers', fontsize = '12')
ax[2].set_xlabel('Types of Passengers', fontsize = '12')
ax[0].set_ylabel('Number of Pssengers', fontsize = '12')
ax[1].set_ylabel('Number of Passengers', fontsize = '12')
ax[2].set_ylabel('Number of Passengers', fontsize = '12')
ax[0].set_title('2020', fontsize = '15')
ax[1].set_title('2021', fontsize = '15')
ax[2].set_title('2022', fontsize = '15')
```

Hi, how do I change specific boxplots to a certain color (eg black & red) I have 2 different states in the boxplot (ACT and NSW) and I want to change the colour of all ACT data to red, and NSW to black. [image]

Comment: With each boxplot pass `palette={'category1': 'color1', 'category2': 'color2'}` parameter with colours you wanted in a dictionary

Comment: @n.shabankin not sure why it didn't work for me though :/

Comment: Thought you had `seaborn.boxplot()`, but it is in fact `matplotlib`. Then you should look up [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/boxplot_color.html)